# Angular - Protected Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

When it comes to pages that only a user who is logged should be able to view, I have a function like this in the controller on that page;

```
if ( user is not logged in ) {

    $state.go('someState')

} else {

    // prepare the page as normal

}
```

Considering I need to write something like this on each page I want to authenticate, I feel maybe there is a more elegant solution.

Should I perform this in the app.run instead? Something like

```
  var protectedPages = a list of protected pages

  if ( protectedPages && user is not logged in ) {

        $state.go('someState')

    } else {

        // prepare the page as normal

    }
```

or is there a more standard approach which is entirely different?

Comment: instead of a whitelist, it would be nice if each page could report the need for login to the checker.

Answer (score 2):

General and I believe best approach for these kind of situation is setting a **page change event** and define logic there...

But for defining logic you need to know about some properties for next state so you can add some data for each state like **requiresLogin**. These properties are completely custom so you can define whatever you want.

Lets define some state which is **requiresLogin**

```
$stateProvider
        .state('exampleState', {
            url: '/example',
            controller: 'ExampleController as vm',
            templateUrl: 'example.html',
            data: {
                requiresLogin: true,
                someOtherCustomProperty: 'It can be anything'
            }
        })
```

as you see **exampleState** has requiresLogin property now in config block we can get this data and allow user to go exampleState or redirect him to some other state.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
        // if next state requires login and user is not loged in
        if (toState.data.requiresLogin && userNotLogedIn) {
            // prevent default behaviour and implement your logic here
            event.preventDefault();

            // TODO

            // as an example you can redirect user to login state
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
```

That's it. All you have to do is put that logic in config block as it should check every state change...

Comment: This looks great, will give it a shot tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: one simple approach is keep all protected pages inside same parent state...then use a resolve on that parent